# Microsoft SharePoint 2010 One to many

Tags: sharepoint

Is it possible to create some kind of one to many relationship between two lists into Microsoft SharePoint 2010? If it's possible i'd like to know how.

Let me know,

Thanks.

Comment: Mediawiki - Sure.  Sharepoint anything - don't know.  Remember: the whole point of Sharepoint is to make simple things seductively easy ... and difficult things utterly impractical (so you have to purchase lots of 3rd party add-ons).  IMHO ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on exactly what you want. You can create a lookup to another list using the custom fields within a list or content type.

But if you want to go to the maximum with one to many relationships then you would have to create a custom field using some custom field using c# code.